# Linear equations without guess elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equations:

$I_1=I_2+I_3$ 

$-7000I_1-4000I_2=42$

$4000I_2-2000I_3=2$

I have added the second equation to the third to get $-7000I_1-2000I_3=44$
But I have left with 2 equations and 3 unknowns.

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: No, you still can use the other equations. It seems you are trying to eliminate $I_2$ Therefore you should also try to eliminate $I_2$ in the first equation. You can solve the second or the third equation for $I_2$ and plug that into the first equation. With the equation you already calculated you now have two equations with both have the variables $I_1$ and $I_3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This system of linear equations has unique solutions
$$
x_1\:=\:-\frac{13}{2500},\:x_2=-\frac{7}{5000},\:x_3=-\frac{19}{5000}
$$
If you do not want to use explicit Gauss elimination (which is what I assume you mean), then you may use the method of row reducing.
See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/AugmentedMatrix.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

First of all when adding equation you're looking to eliminate variables, so don't do this planlessly.

Second all the equations that you produce this way will have to be valid at the solution. You actually don't drop any equationn, but you might not need to use them all. So by adding the second and third equation you end up with four equations and not two.